# Python add item to the tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I have some object.ID-s which I try to store in the user session as tuple. When I add first one it works but tuple looks like `(u'2',)` but when I try to add new one using `mytuple = mytuple + new.id` got error `can only concatenate tuple (not "unicode") to tuple`.

Answer (score 424, accepted):

You need to make the second element a 1-tuple, eg:

```
a = ('2',)
b = 'z'
new = a + (b,)
```

Comment: Why you need this comma

Comment: @SIslam Without the comma, it will just be interpreted as brackets usually used to get around the order of precedence: `(a+b)*c`

Comment: yeah, but you can do `new = a + b` instead of `new = a + (b,)`.   AFAICT, works the same in python3 and python2.7.

Comment: @ILMostro_7 depends what b is though

Comment: Or shortly `a += ('z',)`, as mentioned in [bellow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535123/2989289)

Comment: It's the comma that creates the tuple, not the parentheses. (The only tuple that doesn't require a comma is the empty tuple). The parentheses here ensure that we define a sum of tuples, rather than a tuple consisting of a sum like `a + b,`. (Basically, the comma "operator" has extremely low precedence.)

Answer (score 102):

Since Python 3.5 ([PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)) you can do unpacking within a tuple, list set, and dict:

```
a = ('2',)
b = 'z'
new = (*a, b)
```

Comment: I am trying it on Python 3.7.10, and it works with `a = ('2')`. That is without the additional comma.

Comment: @nocibambi the comma makes it a tuple, without it it's just a string. Try `a = ('23')` and `new` becomes `('2', '3', 'z')`. If you add the comma then you get `('23', 'z')`.

Answer (score 45):

From tuple to list to tuple :

```
a = ('2',)
b = 'b'

l = list(a)
l.append(b)

tuple(l)
```

Or with a longer list of items to append

```
a = ('2',)
items = ['o', 'k', 'd', 'o']

l = list(a)

for x in items:
    l.append(x)

print tuple(l)
```

gives you

```
>>> 
('2', 'o', 'k', 'd', 'o')
```

The point here is: List is a **mutable** sequence type. So you can change a given list by adding or removing elements. Tuple is an **immutable** sequence type. You can't change a tuple. So you have to create a **new** one.

Comment: This will be twice as slow as just adding two tuples

Comment: However if you note to OP to convert to `list` at the beginning, append items, and then at the very end convert to `tuple` then this is the best solution +1

Comment: two items including the first itemin list. but you are right, i should better add a longer=list example, see my edit

Comment: i kinda like this answer the best... while it is probably a bit more expensive, it looks very clean.

Answer (score 21):

Tuple can only allow adding `tuple` to it. The best way to do it is:

```
mytuple =(u'2',)
mytuple +=(new.id,)
```

I tried the same scenario with the below data it all seems to be working fine.

```
>>> mytuple = (u'2',)
>>> mytuple += ('example text',)
>>> print mytuple
(u'2','example text')
```

Answer (score 12):

```
>>> x = (u'2',)
>>> x += u"random string"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    x += u"random string"
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "unicode") to tuple
>>> x += (u"random string", )  # concatenate a one-tuple instead
>>> x
(u'2', u'random string')
```

Answer (score 9):

## #1 form

```
a = ('x', 'y')
b = a + ('z',)
print(b)
```

## #2 form

```
a = ('x', 'y')
b = a + tuple('b')
print(b)
```

Comment: second option does not work. `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Answer (score 4):

If the comma bugs you, you can specify it's a tuple using `tuple()`.

```
ex_tuple = ('a', 'b')
ex_tuple += tuple('c')
print(ex_tuple)
```

Comment: Note: if 'c' is an int, you might as well add the comma (or use ```str(c)```)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

Bottom line, the easiest way to append to a tuple is to enclose the element being added with parentheses and a comma.

```
t = ('a', 4, 'string')
t = t + (5.0,)
print(t)

out: ('a', 4, 'string', 5.0)
```

Answer (score -1):

my favorite:

```
myTuple = tuple(list(myTuple).append(newItem))
```

Yes, I know it is expensive, but it sure looks cool :)

Answer (score -2):

```
tup = (23, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8)
n_tup = tuple(map(lambda x: x+3, tup))
print(n_tup)
```