# Adding a list into a tuple?

Tags: python, list, tuples

These are previously defined.

```
def get_service_code(service):
    return str(service[0])

service_106_data = filter_routes(bus_stations, "106")  #[('106', '1', '1', '43009'), ('106', '1', '2', '43179'), .... ('106', '2', '51', '43009')]
service_106 = make_service(service_106_data, "106")  # ('106', [['43009', '43179',...'43009']])
print(get_service_code(service_106))  --> should return 106
```

bus_stations here is a txt file that contain a list of numbers like this

```
106,1,1,43009
106,1,2,43179
.
.
.
106,2,1,03239
106,2,2,03211
.
.
.
106,2,50,43171
106,2,51,43009
```

Then this is also previously defined

```
def get_route(service, direction):
    return str(service[int(direction)][0])

print(get_route(service_106, '1'))
```

should return this

```
['43009', '43179', '43189', '43619', '43629', '42319', '28109', '28189', '28019', '20109', '17189', '17179', '17169', '17159', '19049', '19039', '19029', '19019', '11199', '11189', '11401', '11239', '11229', '11219', '11209', '13029', '13019', '09149', '09159', '09169', '09179', '09048', '09038', '08138', '08057', '08069', '04179', '02049', 'E0200', '02151', '02161', '02171', '03509', '03519', '03539', '03129', '03218', '03219']

  def make_service(service_data, service_code):
    routes = []
    curr_route = []

    first = service_data[0]  #('106', '1', '1', '43009')
    curr_dir = first[1]   # '1'
    l = list(curr_dir)    # ['1']


    for entry in service_data:
        direction = entry[1] #'1'
        stop = entry[3]  #'43009'

        if direction == curr_dir:   
            curr_route.append(stop) #[43009]
        else:
            routes.append(curr_route)   #[[]]
            curr_route = [stop]         #['43009']
            curr_dir = direction       #not '1'
            l.append(list(direction))  # ['1', __]


    routes.append(curr_route)   #[['43009']]

    #modify this code below
    return (service_code,curr_route)  #("106", [['43009']]) 

service_106 = make_service(service_106_data, "106")

print(service_106)

print(get_service_code((service_106))) # should return 106
```

expected output  for print(service_106) is

```
('106',['1','2'],['03239', '03211', 'E0321', 'E0564', '03222', 'E0599', '03531', '03511', '03501', '02051', '02061', '04111', '04121', '08041', '08031', '08111', '08121', '09059', '09022', '09111', '09121', '09131', '09141', '13011', '13021', '11201', '11211', '11221', '11231', '11419', '11409', '11181', '11191', '19011', '19021', '19031', '19041', '17151', '17161', '17171', '17181', '20101', '28011', '28181', '28101', '42311', '43621', '43611', '43181', '43171', '43009'])
```

Where **['1','2']** suppose to be the newly added list also not only should i be able to add  **['1','2']**  I should be able to add ['A4'] / ['A2','A4'] or other non-numeric list in as well 
I am only suppose to add new lines to the code and modify the last line.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how do I add the list into this tuple. For example how do i put '1' into a list and then add it into the tuple ?

Comment: Not very clear from the question. but, How about `return (service_code + (curr_route, ))  #("106", [43009])`

Comment: Tuples are immutable, so you can’t *add* something to the tuple. You can only create a tuple that has a list as its member.

Comment: This should give you an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730339/python-add-item-to-the-tuple

Comment: I just edited the question maybe this is clearer

Comment: your indentation is incorrect in your question, making it impossible to know for certain what you intend.

Comment: Sorry I edited it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can use:

```
return tuple([service_code] + service_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need

```
return (service_code, list(set(zip(*service_data)[1])), curr_route)  #("106", [['43009']])
```

its very hard to tell though(but this does give the expected output)

using

```
make_service([('106', '1', '1', '43009'), ('106', '1', '2', '43179'), ('106', '2', '51', '43009')],"106")
```

results in `('106', ['1', '2'], ['43009'])`

Comment: Hello Joran thank you for answering. I have just edited the question maybe this is clearer. @Joran

Comment: sorry it is still unclear.  what we would like to see is I have this input (provide the sample input),  when I run it through this code (provide a code sample that we can copy and paste to run) I get this (show output recieved) , however I expect this (show expected output) ... so far only 1 of the four conditions is met (maybe the source is runnable but without input I cannot tell)

Comment: I see... Okay I got my previous defined codes here. @Joran

Comment: so is the list at the top `service_106_data` ? (we're certainly getting closer to a proper question here)

Comment: yes. My problem now is that with these information I have to add ['1','2'] to it such that when i print service_106 it will return a tuple with ['1','2'] @Joran

Comment: service_106_data = filter_routes(bus_stations, "106") which give me [('106', '1', '1', '43009'), ('106', '1', '2', '43179'), .... ('106', '2', '51', '43009')] Note that the second element changes from '1' to '2'

Comment: can you edit your question like so `service_106_data = #put in here ...`

Comment: @user3398505 ok I edited my answer ... im not sure if thats what you are looking for or not ...