# Efficient way to add elements to a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I want to add elements to a tuple. I found 2 ways to do it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16730367/3337089) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1380875/3337089) answers say add two tuples. It will create a new tuple

```
a = (1,2,3)
b = a + (5,)
```

Where as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2309334/3337089) says, convert the tuple to list, add the element and then convert it back to tuple

```
a = (1,2,3)
tmp = list(a)
tmp.insert(3, 'foobar')
b = tuple(tmp)
```

Which among these two is efficient in terms of memory and performance?
Also, suppose I want to insert an element in the middle of a tuple, is that possible using the first method?
Thanks!

Comment: Try to run `timeit` on the methods you mentioned to find out. see e.g. https://www.pythoncentral.io/time-a-python-function/

Comment: The simple answer is: you can not add an item to a tuple. Tuples are immutable. You can on the other hand create a new tuple with that item. But you might want to use a list in the first place.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are only adding a single element, use

```
a += (5, )
```

Or,

```
a = (*a, 5)
```

Tuples are immutable, so adding an element will mean you will need to create a new tuple object. I would not recommend casting to a list unless you are going to add many elements in a loop, or such.

```
a_list = list(a)
for elem in iterable:
    result = process(elem)
    a_list.append(result)

a = tuple(a_list)
```

---

If you want to insert an element in the middle, you can use:

```
m = len(a) // 2
a = (*a[:m], 5, *a[m:])
```

Or,

```
a = a[:m] + (5, ) + a[m:]
```