# Most efficient way to concatenate (or "append to") tuples

Tags: python, performance, tuples

*This question is more about "appending" new items to a tuple, but I wanted to avoid using that word due to the immutable nature of tuples.*

I am aware of two easy ways to concatenate tuples in Python, but I am curious which options is faster / more efficient or if they both behave the same on the low level.

1) Create a new tuple and concatenate them using `+` operator:

```py
oldTuple = (1, 2, 3)
value1 = 4
value2 = 5
result = oldTuple + (value1, value2)
```

2) Unpack the old tuple and construct a new one with the new items:

```py
oldTuple = (1, 2, 3)
value1 = 4
value2 = 5
result = (*oldTuple, value1, value2)
```

**Are both of these ways of tuple concatenation acceptable or is one of them better?**

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Would one become more / less efficient based on the length of the second tuple?

Comment: Some answer there talks about efficiency, the second method being 10 times slower that the first. You can time them using `%timeit`

Comment: More similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984406/efficient-way-to-add-elements-to-a-tuple)

Comment: @Sheldore Oh, thanks, I saw the first question, but I didn't notice any answer mentioning the second option. I'm sorry about that. I wasn't sure if the results would be consistent regardless of size, etc., which is why I asked. Didn't see the second question at all, but it doesn't mention the difference in efficiency.